# Meaning of words colored with Blue and Pink in MSQLSMS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssms, syntax-highlighting

Microsoft SQL Management Studio highlights some special words coloring them in blue or in pink. I would like to know which rule determines the color to use.

For example, consider the two following statements:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
UPDATE myTable SET myFlag = 'X'
```

[image: SELECT * FROM myTable UPDATE myTable SET myFlag = 'X']

`UPDATE` is in pink while `SET`, `SELECT`, & `FROM` are in in blue.

Comment: You can change Keywords to white which is always fun if someone leaves there machine unlocked

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [SSMS > Color Coding in Query Editors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/color-coding-in-query-editors)

```
Color           | Category
----------------|-------------------------------------
Red             | SQL string                                   
Dark green      | Comment                                      
Black on silver | SQLCMD command                               
Magenta         | System function                              
Green           | System table, view, or table-valued function. 
Blue            | Keyword                                      
Teal            | Line numbers or template parameter           
Maroon          | SQL Server stored procedure                  
Dark gray       | Operators
```

Comment: I guess the `UPDATE` color is magenta because it is both a keyword and system function, and the latter takes precedence.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the [full list of reserved keywords](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) broken up by color:

[image: Reserved Keywords by Color]

**Operators** (Grey)

ALL, AND, ANY, BETWEEN, CROSS, EXISTS, IN, INNER, IS, JOIN, LEFT, LIKE, NOT, NULL, OR, OUTER, PIVOT, RIGHT, SOME, UNPIVOT

**System Functions** (Magenta)

COALESCE, COLLATE, CONTAINS, CONVERT, CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_USER, NULLIF, SESSION_USER, SYSTEM_USER, TSEQUAL, UPDATE

**Keywords** (Blue)

ADD, ALTER, AS, ASC, AUTHORIZATION, BACKUP, BEGIN, BREAK, BROWSE, BULK, BY, CASCADE, CASE, CHECK, CHECKPOINT, CLOSE, CLUSTERED, COLUMN, COMMIT, COMPUTE, CONSTRAINT, CONTAINSTABLE, CONTINUE, CREATE, CURRENT, CURRENT_DATE, CURSOR, DATABASE, DBCC, DEALLOCATE, DECLARE, DEFAULT, DELETE, DENY, DESC, DISK, DISTINCT, DISTRIBUTED, DOUBLE, DROP, DUMP, ELSE, END, ERRLVL, ESCAPE, EXCEPT, EXEC, EXECUTE, EXIT, EXTERNAL, FETCH, FILE, FILLFACTOR, FOR, FOREIGN, FREETEXT, FREETEXTTABLE, FROM, FULL, FUNCTION, GOTO, GRANT, GROUP, HAVING, HOLDLOCK, IDENTITY, IDENTITYCOL, IDENTITY_INSERT, IF, INDEX, INSERT, INTERSECT, INTO, KEY, KILL, LINENO, LOAD, MERGE, NATIONAL, NOCHECK, NONCLUSTERED, OF, OFF, OFFSETS, ON, OPEN, OPENDATASOURCE, OPENQUERY, OPENROWSET, OPENXML, OPTION, ORDER, OVER, PERCENT, PLAN, PRECISION, PRIMARY, PRINT, PROC, PROCEDURE, PUBLIC, RAISERROR, READ, READTEXT, RECONFIGURE, REFERENCES, REPLICATION, RESTORE, RESTRICT, RETURN, REVERT, REVOKE, ROLLBACK, ROWCOUNT, ROWGUIDCOL, RULE, SAVE, SCHEMA, SECURITYAUDIT, SELECT, SET, SETUSER, SHUTDOWN, STATISTICS, TABLE, TABLESAMPLE, TEXTSIZE, THEN, TO, TOP, TRAN, TRANSACTION, TRIGGER, TRUNCATE, UNION, UNIQUE, UPDATETEXT, USE, USER, VALUES, VARYING, VIEW, WAITFOR, WHEN, WHERE, WHILE, WITH, WRITETEXT

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to know which rule determines the color to use.

Those colors are defined in SSMS..you can see all here and change them as well:[Color Coding in Query Editor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/scripting/color-coding-in-query-editors)

[image]