# Why does SSMS highlight the word UID as a keyword and what does it mean?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms, syntax-highlighting

In SSMS, given the following statement,

[image]

Why is the word UID highlighted as a keyword?

Secondly, what is UID (or uid)?

Does it relate to GUIDs or User IDs or ...?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55068313/5818960) and [SQL Servers latest T-SQL reserve keyword documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql), it's not a reserved keyword. So why is it highlighted in blue?

And in case your wondering why there's no red syntax error highlighting beneath the word UID, like so:

[image]

... in the the first image above, it's because I'm selecting an existing column named "UID" from a table in a 3rd-party SQL Server database, whose architect(s) chose to name all tables' primary key columns "UID".

Comment: It is a keyword in Oracle. Maybe they're flagging it because of that? I thought I'd be able to come up a solid answer quickly, but I'm not finding anything solid either.

Comment: [Also](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/name-type-words-turns-blue-color-in-query-window) `name`, `type`, `status`...

Comment: For these situations, one puts brackets around column name, like:  [UID]

Comment: Yes @JosephDoggie. I definitely prefer to avoid naming any columns as keywords so I don't have to deal with brackets.

Answer (score 3):

At least for Azure Data Studio(which is a newer product than SSMS):

[sql.tmLanguage.json](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/main/extensions/sql/syntaxes/sql.tmLanguage.json):
**uid** is under section **"name": "keyword.other.sql"**

The provided list is much broader than the one available at: [Reserved Keywords (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and contains values like: `lineage_80_to_100`, `kilobytes_per_batch`, ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because it's a valid SQL Server login account. Bit of info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15

I also found where this UID is a keyword (confirmed in my SSRS Tools>Options>Environment>Fonts and Colors>Display items: Keyword) referencing server user id: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/develop-app/driver-specific-connection-information?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I don't see how a connection string elements would affect highlighting in the SQL editor. If a connection string is to appear there, e.g. in an `opendatasource`, it's a string literal all highlighted in red.

Comment: Perhaps. But colors can be set, too. I couldn't find any other references to UID, so this is about as close as it gets.